# How may two routes with different HTTP request types share the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

In **Rails 3.2** I am using these routes declarations:

```
get 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact'
post 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact'
```

They result in (`rake routes`):

```
contact_en GET    /en/contact(.:format)    contact#new {:locale=>"en"}
contact_de GET    /de/kontakt(.:format)    contact#new {:locale=>"de"}
contact_en POST   /en/contact(.:format)    contact#create {:locale=>"en"}
contact_de POST   /de/kontakt(.:format)    contact#create {:locale=>"de"}
```

Now **Rails 4.0** complains about this configuration:

> Invalid route name, already in use: 'contact'  You may have defined
>   two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be
>   overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same 
>   naming.

Obviously the routes share the same name, but as the request types differ, I'd expect them to be accepted as before.

**How can I tell Rails 4 to generate the routes just like before in 3.2?**

Answer (score 19):

In your situation simply not specifying the `:as` option is sufficient as Rails will automatically get the route name from the path:

```
get 'contact' => 'contact#new'
post 'contact' => 'contact#create'
```

However if you have a more complex path pattern or want to refer to the route with a different name then you should specifically set the second route to `:as => nil` (or `as: nil` using the new hash syntax).

So if you wanted to name the route as `person_path` you would need to do:

```
get 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'person'
post 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => nil
```

Comment: I was looking way to long for this `:as => nil`

Answer (score 12):

If these two routes have the same URL, you don't need to name the second one. So the following should work:

```
get 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact'
post 'contact' => 'contact#create'
```

Comment: That's not valid if you name your route a different `as`, for example, `get 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'some_other_thing'` -- does not get inherited

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use the `:as` ? It seems to be not needed in this case.

```
get 'contact' => 'contact#new'
post 'contact' => 'contact#create'
```

gives

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern        Controller#Action
contact GET  /contact(.:format) contact#new
        POST /contact(.:format) contact#create
```